# Latex listings package ignores last blank line in listing

Tags: latex, listings

I use LaTeX [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package with `\lstinputlisting` to display text from an external file. The file contains a data format description with a blank line at the end. The package ignores the blank line. How can I show the blank line in a listing?

What it displays:

```
1 lorem ipsum...
2 more lorem ipsum
3 lorem lorem ipsum
```

What I want:

```
1 lorem ipsum
2 more lorem ipsum
3 lorem lorem ipsum
4
```

Answer (score 25):

See [the documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), section 4.4

> `showlines=(true|false) or showlines (default = false)
>
> If true, the package prints empty lines at the end of listings. Otherwise these lines are dropped (but they count for line numbering).

Try adding this before your listing:

```
\lstset{
   showlines=true
}
```

Comment: No, this does not work as expected. At least with external file input with **\lstinputlisting**.

Comment: Worked for me with inline listings (I'm not adding line numbers though...).

Answer (score 6):

You can escape to LaTeX from within listings by assigning an escape character like so:

```
\lstset{numbers=left, stepnumber=1, frame=none,basicstyle = \ttfamily}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=\%]
codeline1
codeline2
%
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comes out as:

```
1 codeline1
2 codeline2
3
```

I know it's not `\lstinputlisting` but hopefully it'll help you anyway.